# Total variation of a measure in a topological dual of the space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, bounded-variation, total-variation

I read the definition of total variation of a measure in the following link

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Signed_measure

And then I have a question:

If $\mu$ is a vector measure in $C^*([0,T];\mathbb{R}^{m})$ which is a topological dual of the space of continuous functions. Let $\mu(t)=\mu^i$ for $t\in[t^i,t^{i+1})$, $i=0,\ldots,n-1$, where $t^0=0$, $t^n=T$. Each partition $[t^i,t^{i+1}]$ has a length of $h_n$ which tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Then we have the total variation of $\mu$ 
$$|\mu|([0,T])=\sup\left\{ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\|\mu([t^i,t^{i+1}])\|: \{[t^i,t^{i+1}]\} \textrm{ is a countable partition of } [0,T] \right\}.$$

Can we obtain the following?

\begin{equation}\label{1}
|\mu|([0,T])=\sup\left\{ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\|\mu^i\|\right\}.
\end{equation}
So the uniform boundedness of $\mu$ implies $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\|\mu^i\|$ is uniformly bounded with respect to (w.r.t.) $n$? Is that correct?

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Some things are not understandable. You should edit your question.

Comment: I have just edited it. Is that okay now?

Comment: No. I neither understand the definition of $\mu$ nor is it clear what you take the supremum over.

Comment: We have a countable partition $\{[t^i,t^{i+1}]\}$ of $[0,T]$. Then we define $\mu(t)=\mu^i$ on each interval $[t^i,t^{i+1}]$. And we take the supremum over all the partitions of $[0,T]$.

Comment: And what is $\mu^i$?

Comment: Thank you so much. $\mu^i=\mu(t^i)$, $i=0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: Now, this is getting even more weird. So, you fix a measure $\mu$ and then you define $\mu(t) = \mu(t^i)$??? Note, BTW, that measures act on sets, not on points.

Comment: I see. I got your point. Thank you. So how about if we are given $\mu^i$ as a vector with $m$ coordinates on each interval $[t^i,t^{i+1})$ and then we define $\mu(t)=\mu^i$ on each interval?