# Gaussian Mixture Model: What is a "universal approximator of densities"?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, density-function

When looking into Gaussian Mixture Models (GMMs), I encountered multiple times the statement that "GMMs are a universal approximator of densities" (e.g., [0]).

I'm not sure whether I understand this correctly, and if so, I would need a citeable source for this. The way I understand it is: Given *any* probability density distribution, there exists a GMM (with possibly many components) s.t. the distribution of the GMM approximates the given distribution to within arbitrary error.

My questions:

- Did I understand the above correctly?
- How is the "arbitrary error" specified?
- What source can I cite if I want to use this fact? I could use [0], but the authors also just state this claim without proving it or providing a citation. Is this folklore?

[0]   [Goodfellow, I., Bengio, Y., & Courville, A. (2016). Deep learning., p. 65](https://books.google.de/books?id=omivDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=A%20Gaussian%20mixture%20model%20is%20a%20universal%20approximator%20of%20densities,%20in%20the%20sense%20that%20any%20smooth%20density%20can%20be%20approximated%20with%20any%20specific%20nonzero%20amount%20of%20error%20by%20a%20Gaussian%20mixture%20model%20with%20enough%20components.&source=bl&ots=MMR_gsoITV&sig=ACfU3U1a1Cy40sku8t1q9M0xMqf_oV71EA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi92-bWmc3gAhXIxaYKHSUxBlEQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=A%20Gaussian%20mixture%20model%20is%20a%20universal%20approximator%20of%20densities%2C%20in%20the%20sense%20that%20any%20smooth%20density%20can%20be%20approximated%20with%20any%20specific%20nonzero%20amount%20of%20error%20by%20a%20Gaussian%20mixture%20model%20with%20enough%20components.&f=false)

Comment: I’m not sure about the precise claim, but this seems related to kernel density estimation (KDE) with Gaussian kernels—may or may not help to look there

Comment: It's true but you have to be careful so that it's not false...  See answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a vague/fancy way to say the following simple result.

**But first...some definitions and facts!:**

1. Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)\subset \mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the set of probability (resp. finite signed) Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (with its Euclidean topology).
2. Equip $\mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with the [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak-*_topology)$^{\star}$ topology (somewhat confusingly known in statistics as the topology of weak convergence/convergence in distribution).
3. The point-masses $\{\delta_x\}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}$ span a dense subset of $\mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
   *Note: This is basically why we can to empirical estimation of probability measures.*
4. In this topology, given any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the sequence of Gaussians $(\nu_{x,n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with mean $x$ and variance $\frac1{2^n}$ converge to $\delta_x$.
   *Note: Here just look at the characteristic funciton/ Fourier transforms.*
5. This means that the closed span of the Gaussian measures contains the closed span of the point-masses, which was $\mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
6. The projection of $\mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{R}^d)-\{0\}\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ taking a measure $\mu\mapsto \frac{1}{\mu_+(\mathbb{R}^d)}\mu_+$ is a continous surjection; whence it takes dense sets to dense sets.  Moreover, a direct computation shows that it takes linear combinations to convex combinations.

**Conlusion:**

"Gaussian mixtures" (a.k.a. convex combinatoins of Gaussian measures) are dense in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ **For the weak$^{\star}$** topology!

**Bonuses, fun, and excitment for all:**
Try breaking the argument and showing that linear combinations of Gaussians cannot approximate (non-trivial) point-masses for stronger topologies on $\mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{R}^d)$.  In other words....they aren't capable of approximating all probability measures for the [total variation topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088497/total-variation-of-a-measure-in-a-topological-dual-of-the-space-of-continuous-fu) (another rather standard notion of convergence of measures).

Answer (score 4):

If somebody stumbles across this question, here are some results I was able to find after all. See also [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/aulcd0/gaussian_mixture_model_what_is_a_universal/).

- Linear combinations of Gaussians are dense in L2, i.e., can be made to approximate any square-integrable function arbitrary closely, according to [1]. Kudos to [/u/LeChatTerrible on reddit for finding this](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/aulcd0/gaussian_mixture_model_what_is_a_universal/eh91c6d/)
- I think that [2] with its "Approximation Theorem" pretty much shows what I need.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.3795.pdf

[2] Kostantinos N. Plataniotis and Dimitris Hatzinakos. 2000. Gaussian mixtures and
their applications to signal processing. In Advanced Signal Processing Handbook:
Theory and Implementation for Radar, Sonar, and Medical Imaging Real Time
Systems, Stergios Stergiopoulos (Ed.). CRC Press, Boca Raton, Chapter 3.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but [1] follows from the fact that all bump functions are dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and then you can use some classical results from functional analysis/Radon measure theory to get this in general (since the Lebesgue measure is the prototyical "nice" Radon).